# Get Email value of a people and group field in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

I have a list in SharePoint online that contains a person field, I would like to get the email value of the person/group field and display it within an email.  The workflow runs when an item is created, it then has a loop with a delay ( 1 week) that will check if the person field has been populated.  If the field has not been populated an email is sent to remind them that the field has not been populated.  If the field has been populated a confirmation email should be sent to the user.
[image]

[image]

In the Do Until I am expecting the workflow to check the value after the delay.
[image]

If the value is not null display the values in the email.  But the email values are not showing. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for any and all help.

[image]

Comment: How are you parsing your person type field? You can add a Compose action to see the whether the person column has data or not. Then use that data to Parse JSON to extract email

Comment: Let me know as I've done that before

Comment: I would suggest checking the person field's value in SP first - was that field populated in SharePoint? Have you confirmed that the flow retrieved the value correctly? Once that is confirmed then you can use Parse JSON with schema to map email to a variable.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that today.  I did verify that the person field was populated in SharePoint, it is just not populating in the workflow. But I will try the compose and send you and update.

Comment: Why do you need the "Delay" to pause the flaw? You can use "When an item is created or modified" trigger and conditionally check the value within the flow and process accordingly.

Comment: The delay is because I wanted the users to have a week to update the list before a reminder is sent out to them.

Comment: I guess, for that you could use a recurrence flow and check against the created date of the item and send reminder accordingly. However, that is a different conversation.